# Proper Morphism with Finite Fibers is Finite

Tags: algebraic-geometry, schemes

Let $f: X \to Y$ a morphism between schemes. I'm looking for a reference / sketch for the proof that is $f$ proper amd has finite fibers then $f$ is already finite.

Can the proof redicaly simplified if we assume that $X,Y$ a curves, so  $1$-dimensional, proper $k$-schemes?

Comment: https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/02OG

Comment: Theorem 29.6.2 in Vakil's notes

Comment: There is a more elementary proof for projective morphisms (which includes the special case of curves you are interested in); see \[[Liu](https://mathscinet.ams.org/mathscinet-getitem?mr=1917232), Exercise 4.4.2\] or \[Stacks, footnote in [Tag 0A27](https://stacks.math.columbia.edu/tag/0A27)\].